# save imageButton Visibility [Android]

Tags: java, android

I am making an application for Android and I have difficulties to save the visibility of an `ImageButton` when it is clicked. I search on other topics but i have not found any solutions.

For example, I have a button which become white when it is clicked, and I want to save its visibility when I switch activities or views :

```
OnClickListener oclFavourite = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        ImageButton favWhite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favoriwhite);
        ImageButton favori = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.favorigrey);
        favWhite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //The white button I want to save
        favourite.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //The initial button
    }
};
favori.setOnClickListener(oclFavori);
```

I tried to study `SharedPreferences` function, I succeed to save `TextView` but I don't know how to proceed with `ImageButton` or `ImageView`.

Comment: save its visibility? what do you exactly mean , can you elaborate on that

Comment: for that you have to use the singleton method of java.

Comment: Why u are using two buttons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can toggle a boolean flag whenever you toggle between visibility and invisibility. And then save the flag in `SharedPreferences`. Something like this

```
private boolean flag = true;

private void setvisible(){
    flag = true;
    yourView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
    // save the flag
}

private void setInvisible(){
    flag = false;
    yourView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
    // save the flag
}
```

Now in oncreate

```
onCreate(Bundle b){
    .............
    if(flag)
       // make it visible
    else
       // make it invisible
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sharedpreference to save the visibilty using this like `isButtonVisible = false;`

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor edit = sp.edit();
edit.putBoolean("BUTTON", false);
edit.commit();
```

And then load it using this

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sp.getBoolean("BUTTON",true);
```

And put some condition like

```
if(isButtonVisible==true){
    favWhite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else{
    favWhite.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Ask me if you have any other question.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple . Just have a boolean , switch it to true/false based on your requirement. You can use `SharedPreferences` to get this values later , or you can also make the boolean static(however using static variables is not suggested all times). Also Using one button itself will solve your purpose . Just switch the background or drawable of the button when it is clicked. Also if you are showing two buttons use `view.GONE` instead of `View.Invisible` as making the view gone will totally remove the space taken by the view in the parent instead making it invisble  will only disappear the view but will hold its space. Now coming to the question in the `OnClickListener` of the button use a `boolean isButonclicked =false`in your activity.Now before inflating your button in teh oncreate method of your activity you  check

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
isButonclicked=sp.getBoolean("BUTTON",false);
 buttonSwapping();
```

Now create a method for making which view you want::

```
public void buttonSwapping(){ 
  if(isButonclicked){

  /////  findViewById() your clicked imageView  and set visibilty to Visible.All the 
         imageView set Visibilty as Gone.     

}else{
  /// findViewById() your normal imageView and set visibilty to Visible.
}
  ////Make sure that the visibilty of all the imageview should be set as gone by 
      default in the XML.   
}
```

***Now in the oclicklistener update the  value of your booelan isButonclicked once you click it and put it in the shared pref.***

```
OnClickListener oclFavourite = new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    if(!isbuttonclicked){
        isbuttonclicked=true;
     }else{
         isbuttonclicked=false;
     }

         Editor edit = sp.edit();
         edit.putBoolean("BUTTON", isButonclicked );
         edit.commit();
    ///////accordingly switch your imageviews.You can have a common method and                
       ////implement  that.

        buttonSwapping();
     }
};
```

I think this will solve your problem.